# Can API Management use for api proxy?

Tags: azure, backend

I am new to Azure and I want to use this architecture:

The client side accesses my server , which uses an API key to access another Server A.

Then Server A responds to the client side.

Can Azure API Management do that or do I need to use a function app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure API Management is a front-end/facade for APIs. It doesn't allow you to realize an API flow (call endpoint A, then B, etc.).

In your case, you probably need an Azure Function to do the logic. But if your "server API" only does authentication/authorization, Azure API Management may [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authentication-authorization-overview#gateway-data-plane) it.